# How many Unboxings are taking place?

Tags: java, integer, int, boxing, unboxing

This is my code:

```
Integer x=5;
int y=x+x;
System.out.println(y);
```

And my question is simple. On the first line there's obviously one boxing taking place. But on the next line, are there two unboxings taking place or one? What my question practically means is: Do the two Integer instances x get unboxed, added, and then stored on the int y variable, or the two Integers are added as Integer instances and then the result is unboxed and stored?
P.S. Note that the code above doesn't serve a purpose other than helping me understand the concept of unboxing. 
Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Of course objects can't be added together.

Comment: @user202729: Cuz it demonstrates what a pigs ear has been made of emitting the primitive types into a reference-based language.

Comment: At a certain level, the answer is *"It's none of your business"*, in that the outcome is the same regardless. At another level, it's very likely that *even if the language spec were to state that boxing/unboxing happened*, efficient implementations like HotSpot would optimise away extraneous back/forth conversions.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that **2 unboxing conversions** take place.

The type of `x` is definitely an `Integer`, and the arithmetic expression `x + x` requires both operands to be unboxed. [JLS § 15.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.5) states that

> if the type of an expression is a primitive type, then the value of the expression is of that same primitive type.

Also, according to [§ 15.18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2),

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> <sup><sub>Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).</sub></sup>
>
> The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the promoted type of its operands.

So the resulting type of such an arithmetic expression is a primitive numeric type, so `x + x` yields an `int`.

This result is stored into `y`, without the requirement of conversion.

Comment: You're at odds with my answer. I'll upvote this. Please downvote mine if you know me to be incorrect. Do you think you could quote the JLS inline?

Comment: It's indeed interesting matter. JLS 15.5 states that "if the type of an expression is a primitive type, then the value of the expression is of that same primitive type." After the unboxing of `x` to its primimitive equivalent, one ends with an additive operation with two primitive operands, yielding a primitive value.

Comment: I'm note sure we're quite done yet. I'm saying that the *type* of the expression must be an `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

I did a reality check what the compiler produces:

```
package test;

public class Dummy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer x=5;
        int y=x+x;
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

compiles to:

```
Compiled from "Dummy.java"
public class test.Dummy extends java.lang.Object{
public test.Dummy();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_5
   1:   invokestatic    #16; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   4:   astore_1
   5:   aload_1
   6:   invokevirtual   #22; //Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   9:   aload_1
   10:  invokevirtual   #22; //Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   13:  iadd
   14:  istore_2
   15:  getstatic   #26; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   18:  iload_2
   19:  invokevirtual   #32; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
   22:  return

}
```

We see the boxing of the literal `5` by invoking the static method `java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer`, and we see two unboxings of the `x` variable using `java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I`. The addition result is immediately stored as a primitive into the `y` variable without boxing / unboxing.

But there's still the Hotspot runtime optimizer, I wouldn't be surprised if he found out that `y` is always 10.

Answer (score 0):

**I make it three**; conceptually at least (i.e. assuming no obvious optimisations).

`x` is unboxed once for the left argument of `+` and once again for the right argument of `+`.

The resulting type of that expression is required to be an `Integer`, so the `int` is boxed to an `Integer` with a value 10. That is unboxed again when converting back to `int` in the assignment to `y`.

Note that 5 and 10 are both in the integer cache (part of `Java.lang.Integer`), so no additional objects are actually created.

Comment: `The resulting type of that expression is an Integer: a boxed int with value 10.` Why would that produce a integer wrapper ? :-o after addition isn't that a simple `int` ?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ  I don't think it's supposed to be. The type of summing two `Integer` values is, I'm pretty certain, an `Integer`.

Comment: Ahh .. surprised to know that. Thanks for the clarification. +1.

Comment: I've made a trivial edit to allow the retraction of an upvote.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: I'm in contradiction with another answer. In a decent language you'd just write `decltype(x + x)` and you'd be done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164410/discussion-between---and-bathsheba).